# How can I use a mod in an array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, modulo

Let's say I have an array

```
a = ([6,8,10,13,15,18,21])
```

I have another array

```
b= ([2,5])
```

I want to return an array which gives me nonzero values of a%b. If any value in a mod any value in b equals zero, I don't want to return it.

```
c = ([13,21])
```

Using `numpy.mod(a,b)` returns

> *ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes*

How can I execute this?

Comment: `a[np.mod.outer(a, b).all(1)]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem refers to the fact that numpy cannot apply the `np.mod` operation on the arrays with the given shape, one solution is to reshape, for example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 18, 21]).reshape((-1, 1))
b = np.array([2, 5])

print(a[np.mod(a, b).all(1)].reshape(-1))
```

**Output**

```
[13 21]
```

Note that you need to reshape back to obtain the requested output. The best solution is the one proposed by @PaulPanzer:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 18, 21])
b = np.array([2, 5])

print(a[np.mod.outer(a, b).all(1)])
```

**Output**

```
[13 21]
```

**Further**

1. On numpy broadcasting see [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [2](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.05-computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.html).
2. On [outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html).